# Sql vulnerable script needs fixing

Tags: mysql, sql, lua, sql-injection, code-injection

```
function SetLastCharacter(source, charid)
   MySQLAsyncExecute("UPDATE `user_lastcharacter` SET `charid` = '"..charid.."' WHERE `steamid` = '"..GetPlayerIdentifiers(source)[1].."'")
end
```

This is the code that is vulnerable I need to still be able to use the script however I need this to be fixed any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kindly specify the Langauge.. The solution is to use prepared statements.

Comment: The only language I know uses `..` for string concatenation is Lua. I have added that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just double every single quote and backslash in the text:

```
function SetLastCharacter(source, charid)
   charid = string.gsub(charid, "['\\]", "%0%0")
   local text = GetPlayerIdentifiers(source)[1]
   text = string.gsub(text, "['\\]", "%0%0")
   MySQLAsyncExecute("UPDATE `user_lastcharacter` SET `charid` = '"..charid.."' WHERE `steamid` = '"..text.."'")
end
```